# How many times compile function is called for multiple times usage of same directive on html?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I tried on google, but couldn't find an answer. My concern is..

If I have same custom directive used multiple times on a html page(not in ng-repeat but seperately), how many times compile function of the directive is called?

Comment: Why don't you test it? Add a console.log("called") in the function, and see how many times it's printed. Or increment a global counter, and see which value it has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally Compile will be called only once for entire page(html)

Answer (score 0):

Compile is called once for every DOM element that your directive is attached to.  Link can be called multiple times however, like in the case of ng-repeat for each iteration of the repeat.

Helpful articles on the subject:
http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/28/compile-pre-and-post-linking-in-angularjs.aspx

http://www.jvandemo.com/the-nitty-gritty-of-compile-and-link-functions-inside-angularjs-directives/